# My script does not unzip file

Tags: linux, bash

I downloaded a file from a server in the format `.tar.gz`
my script has the commands

```
tar -zxvf data.tar.gz
rm -rf data.tar.gz
```

When I run this manually it unzips it and displays the contents, and then it deletes the file `data.tar.gz`
However, after running this from the script, when I go in to the folder where it is saved, the file `data.tar.gz` is there, but none of its contents are present

What I do not get is why it does not unzip or get deleted.

Part of the script:

```
OUT=$(date +%Y%m%d -d yesterday)-blah.gz
wget ftp://blah:blah@ftp.haha.com/"$OUT" -O /myFolder/Documents/"$OUT"

tar -zxvf /myFolder/Documents/"$OUT"
#whent the file is unzipped it produces 2 files called abcd and efgh

#because i dont need abcd or the original zipped file
rm -rf /myFolder/Documents/"$OUT"
rm -rf /myFolder/Documents/abcd
```

OK SO ANOTHER UPDATE: When I run this with cron, it does not work, However, when I bash run it, it works.

Comment: Maybe show us the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're not specifying the output directory for tar. By default, it outputs the file from where you're executing the script. You have several fixes available, but the easiest is:

```
OUT=$(date +%Y%m%d -d yesterday)-blah.gz
wget ftp://blah:blah@ftp.haha.com/"$OUT" -O /myFolder/Documents/"$OUT"

cd /myFolder/Documents/
tar -zxvf "$OUT"
#whent the file is unzipped it produces 2 files called abcd and efgh

#because i dont need abcd or the original zipped file
#remember you cd'd here, after we're done ...
rm -rf "$OUT"
rm -rf abcd
#go back
cd -
```

Comment: This does work, thank you very much, however i still do not understand why, the file is saved to documents, the script is run from documents.. I am assuming the contents are unzipped in Documents, so why do I still have to use cd /myFolder/Documents/

Comment: When `cron` starts a job, the current working directory is the home directory of the user under which the `cron` job runs, not the directory containing the script.

Answer (score 1):

Its seem you don't launch your script from the directory your archive is in,
You must use cd command in your script to move to that directory and then launch tar and rm command

Edit:

```
tar -zxvf /myFolder/Documents/"$OUT"
```

tar will extract the archive in the current directory.

Comment: If that was the case, he'd have an error akin to "tar (child): data.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory"

Comment: it does extract the file in Documents.. The script is also stored in Documents

Comment: That's why it work when you launch it in bash, but don't when cron does, you should use erKURITA fix